# comparing tex4ht, lwarp and latexml on same document?

Tags: tex4ht, latexmk, html, lwarp

`tex4ht` and `lwarp` and `latexml` all take a latex file and generate a HTML.

They use different methods.

I'd like to compare the HTML output on some sample document with lots of math and graphics to see how these 3 systems compare. I only used `tex4ht` so far (and `latexhtml` before that).

I know I could go about learning `lwarp` and installing `latexml` (which is a little involved process) and figuring out how to use them and try to do this myself.

But I thought to ask first if someone already did something like this and can share their results. I googled and found no such site that compares these 3 systems on same document.

The only site I know which has HTML generated by `lwarp` is [this](http://bdtechconcepts.com/LaTeX-HTML5-Generation-lwarp-package.html) but it does not have much math there. *Any one knows of other sites?*

For `latexml` I know of https://dlmf.nist.gov/ which uses Latexml. *Any one knows of other sites*?

### Update and MWE

Here is a MWE I just made up. I tried to add to it things which are useful (I should have added table also but forgot).

It has some images, a code listing, some math, uses the book class with some chapters and sections.

I will show the MWE and the `tex4ht` command used to compile it. I put the source and the small tex4ht .cfg file and the HTML output in a zip file. So it is all in one folder. The command to compile is

```
  make4ht -u -c ./nma.cfg foo.tex "html,pic-align"
```

Where `nma.cfg` is

```
\Preamble{xhtml,p-width}    
%need this below for MATH.
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
\begin{document}    
\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
\Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class="math";align="absmiddle"}     
\EndPreamble
```

The image used is the standard one in texlive distribution called `example-image`. But sometimes tex4ht does not see this image file, so I also included this image as `.png` in the zip file if needed.

The zip file is in this folder on my own web page  [here](https://www.12000.org/tmp/022518/)

Here is a listing of the MWE. This compiles OK with lualatex also. The HTML generated and the PDF file also is below the code listing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\raggedbottom                                  

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.PDF,.png,.PNG,.jpg,.jpeg,.JPG,.JPEG}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab,%
    breaklines=true,%
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red}, %some words to emphasise
}


\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{etex} %adds more registers
\usepackage{upquote} %to handle correct tex4ht to html conversion of `
\newcommand{\authorMe}[0]
 {\author{\footnotesize \href{mailto:user@comain}{John Doe}}}%

\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=.8in,bottom=.8in,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}

\begin{document}   

\begin{description}
\item[] \href{/index.htm}{home}
\item[] \href{../index.htm}{up}
\end{description}

\title{My big title}
\authorMe
\date{Spring 2018 \hspace{.2in} \tiny{Compiled on \today\ at \currenttime}}
\maketitle  

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{Introduction} 
This is main chapter. Here is a nice image

\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}

\section{some math}

\blindtext
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{theorem}[Residue Theorem]
Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated 
singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed 
rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the 
points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\! f = \sum_{k=1}^m 
  n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
\]
\end{theorem}

\subsection{this is a subsection}

Here is some code in minipage

\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\footnotesize]
%check if we converged or not
if k>opt.MAX_ITER || gradientNormTol(k)<=opt.gradientNormTol ...
|| (k>1 && levelSets(k)>levelSets(k-1))% check for getting worst
   keepRunning = false;
else
  ....
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

Here is example using listings

\begin{lstlisting}
%Evaluate J(u) at u
function f = objectiveFunc(u)
 u=u(:);
 N = size(u,1);
 f = 0;
 for i = 1:N-1
     f  = f + 100*(u(i+1)-u(i)^2)^2 + (1-u(i))^2;
 end
end
\end{lstlisting}


\subsubsection{This is subsubsection with images}

These two images should be side by side
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Contour $J(u)$}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Zooming on $J(u)$}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\chapter{This is a new chapter}
Here is some verbatim

\begin{Verbatim}
K>> gradientNormTol(end-6:end)
....
          16.1440020280613
           17.487837406306
           16.092991548592
          17.4442963174089
\end{Verbatim}

\section{This is a section for more math}

\subsection{problem 1}
\underline{problem} Transform the following problem or system to set of first
order ODE $t^{2}x^{\prime\prime}+tx^{\prime}+\left(  t^{2}-1\right)  x=0$

\underline{solution} Since this is second order ODE, we need two state
variables, say $x_{1},x$

Let $x_{1}=x,x_{2}=x^{\prime}$, hence%
\[
\left.
\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
x_{1}=x\\
x_{2}=x^{\prime}%
\end{array}
\right\}  \overset{\text{take derivative}}{\longrightarrow}\left.
\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
x_{1}^{\prime}=x^{\prime}\\
x_{2}^{\prime}=x^{\prime\prime}%
\end{array}
\right\}  \overset{\text{replace RHS}}{\longrightarrow}%
\begin{array}
[c]{c}%
x_{1}^{\prime}=x_{2}\\
x_{2}^{\prime}=-\frac{x^{\prime}}{t}-\frac{\left(  t^{2}-1\right)  x}%
{t}=-\frac{x_{2}}{t}-\frac{\left(  t^{2}-1\right)  x_{1}}{t}%
\end{array}
\]
Hence the two first order ODE's are (now coupled)%
\begin{align*}
x_{1}^{\prime}  &  =x_{2}\\
x_{2}^{\prime}  &  =-\frac{x_{2}}{t}-\frac{\left(  t^{2}-1\right)  x_{1}}{t}%
\end{align*}
The matrix form of the above is%
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}^{\prime}  &  =A\mathbf{x}\\%
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}^{\prime}\\
x_{2}^{\prime}%
\end{pmatrix}
&  =%
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-\frac{t^{2}-1}{t} & -\frac{1}{t}%
\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}%
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\subsection{Example on page 500, textbook (Edwards\&Penny, 3rd edition)}

\underline{problem} This problem was solved in textbook using matrix
exponential. Here is solved using the fundamental matrix only. Use the method
of variation of parameters to solve $\mathbf{x}^{\prime}=A\mathbf{x}%
+\mathbf{f}\left(  t\right)  $.%
\begin{align*}
A &  =%
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2\\
3 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\bar{f}\left(  t\right)   &  =%
\begin{pmatrix}
-15\\
4
\end{pmatrix}
te^{-2t}\\
\bar{x}\left(  0\right)   &  =%
\begin{pmatrix}
7\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}


\underline{Solution}

The homogeneous solution was found in the book as%

\[
\bar{x}_{h}=c_{1}%
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-2t}+c_{2}%
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
e^{5t}%
\]
Following scalar case, the guess would be $\bar{x}_{p}=\left(  \bar{b}+\bar
{a}t\right)  e^{-2t}$ but since $e^{-2t}$ is in the homogeneous, we have to
adjust to be $\bar{x}_{p}=\left(  \bar{b}t+\bar{a}t^{2}\right)  e^{-2t}%
+\bar{c}e^{5t}$. Notice we had to add $\bar{c}e^{5t}$, else it will not work
if we just guessed $\bar{x}_{p}=\left(  \bar{b}t+\bar{a}t^{2}\right)
e^{-2t}\,$\ based on what we would do in scalar case, we will find we get
$\bar{a}=\bar{b}=0$. This seems to be a trial and error stage and one just
have to try to find out. This is why undermined coefficients for systems is
not as easy to use as with scalar case. Hence
\[
\bar{x}_{p}=\left(  \bar{b}t+\bar{a}t^{2}\right)  e^{-2t}+\bar{c}e^{5t}%
\]
Now we plug-in this back into the ODE\ and solve for $\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c}%
$. But an easier method is to use Variation of parameters. The fundamental
matrix is%
\begin{align*}
\Phi & =%
\begin{pmatrix}
\bar{x}_{1} & \bar{x}_{2}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
& =%
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-2t} & 2e^{5t}\\
-2e^{-2t} & e^{5t}%
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
And
\[
\Phi^{-1}=\frac{%
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{5t} & 2e^{-2t}\\
-2e^{5t} & e^{-2t}%
\end{pmatrix}
^{T}}{\left\vert \Phi\right\vert }=\frac{%
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{5t} & -2e^{5t}\\
2e^{-2t} & e^{-2t}%
\end{pmatrix}
}{e^{3t}+4e^{3t}}=\frac{1}{5}%
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{2t} & -2e^{2t}\\
2e^{-5t} & e^{-5t}%
\end{pmatrix}
\]
Hence using
\begin{align*}
\bar{x}_{p}  & =\Phi\int\Phi^{-1}\bar{f}\left(  t\right)  dt\\
& =\frac{1}{5}\Phi\int%
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{2t} & -2e^{2t}\\
2e^{-5t} & e^{-5t}%
\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix}
-15te^{-2t}\\
4te^{-2t}%
\end{pmatrix}
dt\\
& =\frac{1}{5}\Phi\int%
\begin{pmatrix}
-23t\\
-26te^{-7t}%
\end{pmatrix}
dt
\end{align*}
The integral of  $\allowbreak\int-23tdt=\frac{-23}{2}t^{2}$ and $\int%
-26te^{-7t}dt=\allowbreak\frac{26}{49}e^{-7t}\left(  7t+1\right)  $ (using
integration by parts) hence the above simplifies to%
\begin{align*}
\bar{x}_{p}  & =\Phi%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-23}{10}t^{2}\\
\frac{26}{245}e^{-7t}+\frac{26}{35}te^{-7t}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
& =%
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-2t} & 2e^{5t}\\
-2e^{-2t} & e^{5t}%
\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-23}{10}t^{2}\\
\frac{26}{245}e^{-7t}+\frac{26}{35}te^{-7t}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
& =%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{52}{245}e^{-2t}+\frac{52}{35}te^{-2t}-\frac{23}{10}t^{2}e^{-2t}\\
\frac{26}{245}e^{-2t}+\frac{26}{35}te^{-2t}+\frac{23}{5}t^{2}e^{-2t}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
& =%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{490}e^{-2t}\left(  -1127t^{2}+728t+104\right)  \\
\frac{1}{245}e^{-2t}\left(  1127t^{2}+182t+26\right)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Hence the complete solution is%
\begin{align*}
\bar{x}  & =\bar{x}_{h}+\bar{x}_{p}\\
& =c_{1}%
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-2t}+c_{2}%
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
e^{5t}+%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{490}e^{-2t}\left(  -1127t^{2}+728t+104\right)  \\
\frac{1}{245}e^{-2t}\left(  1127t^{2}+182t+26\right)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
To find the constants, we apply initial conditions. At $t=0$%
\begin{align*}%
\begin{pmatrix}
7\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
& =c_{1}%
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
+c_{2}%
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
+%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{52}{245}\\
\frac{26}{245}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\
c_{1}%
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
+c_{2}%
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
& =%
\begin{pmatrix}
7\\
3
\end{pmatrix}
-%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{52}{245}\\
\frac{26}{245}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\%
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
-2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{1}\\
c_{2}%
\end{pmatrix}
& =%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1663}{245}\\
\frac{709}{245}%
\end{pmatrix}
\\%
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}%
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{1}\\
c_{2}%
\end{pmatrix}
& =%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1663}{245}\\
\frac{807}{49}%
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Hence $5c_{2}=\frac{807}{49}$ or $c_{2}=\frac{807}{245}$ and $c_{1}%
+2c_{2}=\frac{1663}{245}$, hence $c_{1}=\frac{1663}{245}-2\left(  \frac
{807}{245}\right)  =\frac{1}{5}$. Therefore the solution becomes%
\[
\bar{x}=\frac{1}{5}%
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-2t}+\frac{807}{245}%
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
e^{5t}+%
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{490}e^{-2t}\left(  -1127t^{2}+728t+104\right)  \\
\frac{1}{245}e^{-2t}\left(  1127t^{2}+182t+26\right)
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

This is how the [HTML looks like](https://www.12000.org/tmp/sample/foo.html) generated by tex4ht using the above command

How does this file look in latexml HTML? lwarp HTML?

This is the [PDF file](https://www.12000.org/tmp/sample/foo.pdf) generated by lualatex if needed.

Comment: https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/ uses LaTeXML.

Comment: Do you have a sample document to test?

Comment: @michal.h21 Sure. I have many examples of my own. But I do not have a MWE for this. Should I make one? The problem is if I add images, and such, will be hard to post it here. I can make one without images?

Comment: @Nasser: Users with 300 reputation and more (which you definitely have by now) can add new tags... I've done this for you this time ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks. I did not know I have the power to add tags! I thought only moderators can do this.

Comment: @michal.h21 Ok, I am working on one now. I am trying to add features to it that are useful and see how it will look in HTML. It will take me little bit more time.

Comment: @Nasser [here](https://www.kodymirus.cz/samples/nasser/comparison/foo.html) is your sample file with different configuration and pre-generated MathJax output from MathML

Comment: @michal.h21  Thanks. The output you have looks really nice. Only issue I have is the math. If you notice in "2.1.1 problem 1", how all the primes are too small as in $x'$ and $x''$ Compare this to svg output using configuration in my post.  I do not know if this is just mathjax configuration issue or something else.

Comment: @Nasser it is how MathJax renders it, they are bigger in MathML

Comment: it looks to have made the equivalent of `<msup>'` rather than `<msup>&prime;` although of course if the font doesn't have a full size prime character the render needs to special case that back to `x'` (is that the new common-html output from mathjax? @michal.h21

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, it is common-html. it is possible that `&prime;` is translated to `′` by `make4ht`, because it translates most entities to unicode.

Comment: @michal.h21 yes sure the entity and the unicode character should act the same way I just used the entity name on the comment to make it readable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it seems that it is a issue with `common-html` output, client-side MathJax with HTML renders it correctly: https://www.kodymirus.cz/samples/nasser/comparison/foo2.html

Comment: @Nasser why have you used `x^{\prime}` and `x^{\prime\prime}` rather than `x'` and `x''` as noted above prime often needs special handling and using unusual input forms makes that harder

Comment: @DavidCarlisle some of the code I copied from my latex files generated by Scientific Word which always uses `\prime`. I am using SW version 5.5 for years now. They have new version 6.0, but I am sticking to 5.5, since version 6.0 uses XML which I do not like. There is no way to tell SW not to use `\prime`

Comment: for details about the MathJax-Node compilation see https://www.kodymirus.cz/samples/mathjaxnode/maths.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A substantial `lwarp` example is [here](https://people.bath.ac.uk/feb/ma20216/notes): this is a 65 page set of lecture notes for a course I teach.  It includes `tikz` graphics, `cleveref` references and a lot of maths.  I had to supply some js and css to tweak the final output but `lwarp` did all the heavy lifting.

I have tried `latexml` on the same document but couldn't get `cleveref` to work.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Without source to the example, it is next to useless... but it looks *very* nice.

Comment: @vonbrand: well, the whole point of `lwarp` is that you take your existing LaTeX source, add a few lines to the preamble and you are good to go.  Of course, in 65 pages, you will need a couple of tweaks but I am not sure how informative the source would be.

Comment: Another very nice example is https://tikz.dev/ --- the source is on GitHub at https://github.com/DominikPeters/pgf-tikz-html-manual